# Large unknown data from db to code

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, dataset, memorystream

I have to get a big amount of different records (1000.000) from my db to build a report from this data. My DB is on a remote system. Now I have different sql statements for each report. This sql statements are send to the service. The service fills a DataSet and returns  this to my application. Now I can bind the DataSet to my reports.
The problem is that DataSets with thid number of records have a enormous memory consumption. I mean if I load the data the memory rises to 1gb for one loading.

Is there an alternative to load data without this memory consumption?
I mean I already use ORM like NHibernate, but the problem is that I don't know the data that will be loaded, there are hundreds of reports with different sql statements that can be changed, so I cannot create hundreds of classes to map...

Edit :

Here is my example code that I am using:

```
     DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
     try
     {
        using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(strConnString))
        {
           connection.Open();
           using (FbCommand cmd =
              new FbCommand(
                 "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;",
                 connection))
           {
              FbDataAdapter fbd = new FbDataAdapter(cmd);
              fbd.Fill(dataSet);
              // This is what the default ADO.Net provider can do..
              //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
              //System.Xml.XmlReader reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader();
           }
        }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question you should ask is: How much DATA is it and what is the memory OVERHEAD. If the OVERHEAD is large, you need to find a better data structure. If the DATA itself is too large for memory, you need to explore ways to only bring part of it into memory at a time.

In either case, using NHibernate for reporting on such large volumes is dubious - it can be useful to use existing mapped classes to construct queries, but you must include a projection to a simple unmapped DTO class or to an object[] or similar, to avoid NHibernate instantiating mapped classes for all the results - the latter would be bad for both performance and memory consumption.

Oh, and did you mean that you have a web service that returns a DataSet? That is considered bad style in general, because the DataSet class is Microsoft-specific, and for various other reasons (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx).

Comment: The webservice is only used by my application. I have to load the data from the db and a DataSet was the only way to do it, by the way I am using firebird and ADO.Net provider. If I would parse the DataSet to XML or Json or something else there would be an additional performance issue. I mean if there is a possibility to directly load the data to XML that would be better, but nothing found so far. Only way is to load it to a DataSet and then write it to XML. The oroginal SQLCommand class has something like an ExecuteXmlReader() but there is nothing like this Firebird provider (FBCommand).

Comment: Something is off here... The basic return structure from ADO.Net is a *DataReader*, not a DataSet. While the framework provides convenience methods to read a DataReader into a DataSet, to my knowledge this is something that the user of ADO.Net has to perform explicitly.

Comment: @Franki1986 Exactly as I said - you have additional code to convert from DataReader to DataSet, in the form of calling FbDataAdapter. There is nothing "default" about SqlCommand - it is simply a built-in ADO.Net provider specific for Microsoft SQL Server. FbCommand may not have the ExecuteXmlReader which appears to be a MS-specific extension, but the true most basic method is *ExecuteReader()*, which will return a DataReader that you can then read row-for-row into a suitable datastructure. This should have the least overhead.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answers! Do you think there is a better solution that won't consumes this massive memory with getting xml?